# rlogin: how to fail immediately when any condition fails?

Tags: linux, unix, authentication

I want to be able to login as user 'ben' from any machine listed in hosts.equiv. But in case some other hosts tries to login, I would like to fail immediately rather give it 3 more chances. Here's my current behaviour:

```
This host is not listed in hosts.equiv of the server
Linux(10.0.0.4)# rlogin -l ben 10.0.0.2
Login incorrect

login: ben
Password:
Login incorrect

login: admin
Password:
Login incorrect

login: root
Password:

Login incorrect
rlogin: connection closed.
```

Here's my pam.d config for rlogin:

```
auth       required        pam_nologin.so
auth       required        pam_unix.so nullok
auth       required        pam_rhosts.so  ## I have tried requisite too
account    required        pam_unix.so
password   required        pam_unix.so nullok
session    required        pam_unix.so
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why don't you use `ssh` ?

Comment: I use a pre-compiled binary (which uses rlogin) that expects the connection to be terminated immediately upon auth failure. It can't handle interactive logins.

Comment: `ssh` can be configured to work without passwords (using public keys)

Comment: While true, the binary uses rlogin, not ssh. I don't have the source code for it either :/